# Is it legitimate to insert UUIDs into Postgres that have been generated by a client application?

Tags: postgresql, uuid, offline, offlineapps

The normal MO for creating items in a database is to let the database control the generation of the primary key (id). That's usually true whether you're using auto-incremented integer ids or UUIDs.

I'm building a clientside app (Angular but the tech is irrelevant) that I want to be able to build offline behaviour into. In order to allow allow offline object creation (and association) I need the the client appplication to generate primary keys for new objects. This is both to allow for associations with other objects created offline and also to allow for indempotence (making sure I don't accidentally save the same object to the server twice due to a network issue).

The challenge though is what happens when that object gets sent to the server. Do you use a temporary clientside ID which you then replace with the ID that the server subsequently generates or you use some sort of ID translation layer between the client and the server - [this is what Trello did when building their offline functionality](https://tech.trello.com/sync-two-id-problem/).

However, it occurred to me that there may be a third way. I'm using UUIDs for all tables on the back end. And so this made me realise that I could in theory insert a UUID into the back end that was generated on the front end. The whole point of UUIDs is that they're universally unique so the front end doesn't need to know the server state to generate one. In the unlikely event that they do collide then the uniqueness criteria on the server would prevent a duplicate.

Is this a legitimate approach? The risk seems to be 1. Collisions and 2. any form of security that I haven't anticipated. Collisons seem to be taken care of by the way that UUIDs are generated but I can't tell if there are risks in allowing a client to choose the ID of an inserted object.

Comment: There's no security risk *per se*. It depends on what your app does and your API allows whether there's something an attacker could do by being able to specify ids that they otherwise wouldn't be…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it occurred to me that there may be a third way. I'm using UUIDs for all tables on the back end. And so this made me realise that I could in theory insert a UUID into the back end that was generated on the front end. The whole point of UUIDs is that they're universally unique so the front end doesn't need to know the server state to generate one. In the unlikely event that they do collide then the uniqueness criteria on the server would prevent a duplicate.

Yes, this is fine. [Postgres even has a UUID type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html).

Set the default ID to be [a server-generated UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) if the client does not send one.

> 1. Collisions.

UUIDs are designed to not collide.

> 2. Any form of security that I haven't anticipated.

Avoid UUIDv1 because...

> This involves the MAC address of the computer and a time stamp. Note that UUIDs of this kind reveal the identity of the computer that created the identifier and the time at which it did so, which might make it unsuitable for certain security-sensitive applications.

You can instead use [`uuid_generate_v1mc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html#id-1.11.7.53.5) which obscures the MAC address.

Avoid UUIDv3 because it uses MD5. Use UUIDv5 instead.

[UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) is simplest, it's a 122 bit random number, and built into Postgres (the others are in the commonly available [uuid-osp extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html#id-1.11.7.53.5)). However, it depends on the strength of the random number generator of each client. But even a bad UUIDv4 generator is better than incrementing an integer.